# Continual SSL Certificate Error Problems in Mac Terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

In my Mac Terminal, any time I try to download a new Python package, I get this error:

after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))

I've tried a bunch of things to fix it, I downloaded the most recent version of Python and tried pip install certifi, but I was getting the same error when I tried that. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.